# Software center freezes in Ubuntu 12.04, how can I fix it?

Tags: 12.04

Every time I open it up it freezes. I'm going to try to re-install it. Still, anyway to fix this? Thank you for your time.

PF: Still learning how to use Ubuntu so sorry if I'm not being descriptive enough.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [reporting this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). ([This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) also has some good information about bug reporting.) This will probably be closed as off-topic, in accordance with [the FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) and [this policy](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/228/22949).

Answer (score 2):

The software center does tend to freeze, especially on older or slower machines, just because it is so big. Try using Synaptic instead:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

It's a bit less newbie-friendly, but easy enough to find your way around and get done what you need to.